# How to bind Radio Buttons using RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, radio-group, rx-android

I'm following the code of the [Qiitanium](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/Qiitanium/blob/a0e6fe47c7e28f760d3827b9acec5a8ec7163426/qiitanium/src/main/java/com/ogaclejapan/qiitanium/presentation/view/ArticleListItemView.java#L64-L74) app (See the highlighted lines in link) and I have trouble figuring out how I can bind RadioButtons

Say I have a RadioGroup with R.id.rgMyButtons as Id and it contains 3 RadioButtons "Dead", "Alive", "Body Missing" with Ids are R.id.rbDead, R.id.rbAlive, R.id.rbMissing

I set the RadioGroup field as

```
Rx<RadioGroup> radioGroup;
```

I get the view set in onViewCreated as

```
rdGroup = RxView.findById(this, R.id.rgMyButtons);
rdGroup.get().setOnCheckedChangeListener(mOnPersonStateUpdateListener);
```

In onBind, I'd like to bind the RadioGroup to the model data so that the value which returns maps directly to the correct RadioButton in that group. I'm looking for something like

```
rdGroup.bind(person.state(), RxActions.someAction()),
```

So that it is bound to the RadioGroup and automatically sets the correct value.

The person_state() actually returns 2 for Dead, 3 for Alive and 4 for Missing and I want that to check to the correct field in RadioGroup. How can I achieve this in RxAndroid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this on my own. Here's the answer for  anyone who might come across the same issue....

I wrote a function in the class as

```
protected RxAction<RadioGroup, String> setRadioButton() {
    return new RxAction<RadioGroup, String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final RadioGroup radioGroup, final String selection) {
           RadioButton rb;
           switch(selection)
           {
               case "2":
                   rb = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbDead);
                   rb.setChecked(true);
                   break;

               case "3":
                   rb = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbAlive);
                   rb.setChecked(true);
                   break;

               case "4":
                   rb = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbMissing);
                   rb.setChecked(true);
                   break;

           }
        }
    };
}
```

And inside the onBind I used

```
rdGroup.bind(person.state(), setRadioButton()),
```