# Android RxJava React to RadioButton Events

Tags: android, events, radio-button, rx-java

I started to learn and understand RxJva / RxAndroid and I have a simple Question.
I have a class `Foo` with two `RadioButtons` `BarOn` and `BarOff`. In my second class `Bar` I want react on a check to handle `BarOn` and `BarOff` events. How can implement this with RxJava?

Comment: In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180429/how-to-bind-radio-buttons-using-rxjava) post author creats a good solution

Comment: @Kroha, thank you for your post. I checked this post before also but as beginner it is very hard to understand what is happening there